# How to create Raw socket in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, raw-sockets

Has anybody tried creating `RawSocket` in `Android` and have succeeded ?

Answer (score 10):

So far as I'm aware access to raw sockets is not availables in **any** pure Java library.

In part this is because on most O/S access to raw sockets is a privileged operation, only available to processes running as root / administrator.

The `Socket` and `DatagramSocket` classes available in the `java.net` package are implicitly IP sockets (for TCP, and UDP, respectively).

See for more detail at [Apple Lists - Java raw sockets](https://lists.apple.com/archives/Java-dev/2004/Jul/msg00086.html).

Answer (score 3):

I havent actually created any raw sockets in Android but the java.net and javax.net packages shold do what you need,

[java.net package overview](http://code.google.com/android/reference/java/net/package-summary.html)

[javax.net package overview](http://code.google.com/android/reference/javax/net/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Raw sockets are not supported in any Java or Android libraries

Use 3rd party libraries:
[RockSaw](https://www.savarese.org/software/rocksaw/index.html)
[JSocket](http://jswrench.sourceforge.net/)